# How many nested controls can be created?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a `UserControl` containing a `FlowLayoutPanel`. A lot of this control instances are needed to be used in a nested form on the `Form`. I found it out that *only* 15 nested instances can be created! So I decided to check a more simple model of my control out. The model consist of a `GroupBox` that contains a `Panel`:

```
Control parent = this;
for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < 100; groupIndex++)
{
    GroupBox grp = new GroupBox();
    Panel pnl = new Panel();
    pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pnl.Parent = grp;

    grp.Parent = parent;
    grp.Size = new Size(parent.Width - 10, parent.Height - 10);

    parent = pnl;
}
```

When `groupIndex` reaches to 24, it encounters the *Error creating window handle* exception. What's the reason for and how to overcome it?

Thanks

Comment: You should check out [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx)

Comment: See if this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winforms/thread/84F3FFBE-DA0B-43C9-8565-2BDA39003655) and this [Bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Error+creating+window+handle+exception&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=error+creating+window+handle+exception&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=) shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for nesting things this deep?

Comment: @ConradFrix: Thanks-- I read Mark Russinovich article. As he mentioned _There are two limits related to the number of handles a process can create: **1-** the maximum number of handles the system sets for a process and **2-** the amount of memory available to store the handles and the objects the application is referencing with its handles._ But none of them is hold here! isn't?

Comment: @minitech: Yeah! The UI is used in a management application and should be able to contain a series of procedure charts in a nested form.

Comment: @Mimi: Hm... okay. Tough luck! Is drawing anything using GDI+ to remove a layer of controls possible?

Comment: @minitech :) It's possible but turns some of my application features off. (e.g. my controls are furnished by drag & drop ability, so they can easily be nested.)

Comment: @MarkHall: Thanks-- I checked it. As far as I searched, such a problem is usually due to maximum number of handles which doesn't seem to be true here.

Answer (score 1):

This a duplicate of the following question:

[Control Nesting Limits in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060438/control-nesting-limits-in-winforms)

To answer your question, Windows has a limit of 50 nested controls ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/18/44379.aspx)).

Your sample creates a group box and nests a panel inside of it, and you do this 24 times before the crash occurs. If you account for the form itself, you are hitting that limit.

The limit is enforced when the controls are drawn. From my testing, I was able to create and nest many hundreds of controls, but when I added the top level control of that nest to a visible control, it still crashed.