# Control Nesting Limits in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, nested-controls

I'm creating my form's controls in the runtime, and for some reason, I need the depth to be more than 49 nested controls (i.e. control is contained in another one).

but the following error appears:

[image: Exception]

How can I add more controls nested in each other ?

Here is a little piece of code that may reproduce the error:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Panel lastPanel = panel1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Panel newPanel = new Panel();
            lastPanel.Controls.Add(newPanel);
            lastPanel = newPanel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " I need the depth to be more than 49 nested controls " - do you really?

Comment: @MitchWheat
mmmmm yes indeed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Raymond Chen you cannot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/18/44379.aspx), it was a deliberate decision on the part of the windows executive developers.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I have encountered this exact issue in one component of our company's application.