# Nested control bluescreen with latest Windows Creators Update

Tags: c#, windows, crash, nested, controls

Recently I updated to the new Windows Creators edition (version 1703) and I’m getting a similar issue to this post [Control Nesting Limits in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060438/control-nesting-limits-in-winforms)
, I have a limit of 33 nested controls on my machine using WinForms.

The difference is that my machine Bluescreens. My biggest concern of course is our Users will start experiencing similar problems when they update.

We are currently in the process of creating a custom control to lower memory usage, but it would be good to get to the bottom of why it's bluescreening.

My system log shows that it’s an unexpected kernel mode trap, 0x1000007f. I’ve tried disabling drivers to eliminate any hardware issues without any success. All hardware checks pass.

Has anyone else had a similar issue with bluescreening?

Also, there is a hotfix for a nested control issue in Windows 8, but I can’t find any additional information about how it was fixed [Hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2870007/-0x0000007f-stop-error-when-you-move-the-mouse-pointer-over-nested-windows-in-windows-8-or-windows-server-2012). If anyone has info on this it may be helpful.

Regards

Comment: You are not the first to run into this new behavior.  Windows always had a hard upper limit on child window nesting depth, what's new in Creators is that this limit appears to have been lowered, otherwise without a check that makes it fail more gracefully.  Creators is shaping up to be the next Vista, lots of deep changes in the windowing sub-system with programs failing all over the place.  If you don't want to call Microsoft Support then the only sensible thing to do is to redesign your UI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I've already gone down the Microsoft Support path with little success. We have a couple of other machines experiencing the same issue now so redesigning the UI to a reasonable nesting depth. I will be uploading minidumps to the support site so will post back here as (when) I get more information.